# How to serialize a record / row in SQL?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to serialize a record/row in SQL? And conversely, to deserialize something that has been serialized.

By serialize, I mean put all of the fields in a record into one field or string.

Preferably with MySQL compatibility.

I am guessing that xml, a udf or stored procedure might be necessary.

is there a way to use xml or json directly in sql/mysql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I feel my answer may lack what you are looking for but with out more context here are a couple options:

1. Use the mysqldump command.

   mysqldump -u user -pPassword   --no-create-db --no-create-info --where="primary_key=N"

will give you a sql insert command which you can use to reconstruct that row.

1. run a query like

   select * into outfile '/tmp/rowdump.data' from table where primary_key=N

This will create a file /tmp/rowdump.data in tab separated format.  This can be reimported with

```
load data infile '/tmp/rowdump.data' into table `table`;
```

If these don't suit your needs please elaborate on your use case on what you are trying to accomplish.